# Email template not rendering correctly in Gmail Client Iphone

Tags: html, css, html-email

How to make email-templates with a fixed-width for Iphone? If a width is longer than viewport - reduce the scale.

Now the issue I am having seems to be possibly with email sizing within Gmail Client on iOS on the iPhone. Although this template seems to look ok in all clients, the result I am getting in Gmail Client on Iphone looks compressed:

Email template rendering in Android:
[image: Email template rendering in Android]

Email template rendering in IOS(Iphone):
[image: Email template rendering in IOS]

Html code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <title>Performance Scorecard</title>
</head>

<body>
  <table width="640" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="3" style="font-family:                   'Trebuchet MS', Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 15px;">
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" style="padding-bottom: 5px; text-align: left;">Hi <span>{FirstName}</span>,</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" style="padding-bottom: 5px; text-align: left;">Your Performance Scorecard for the month of <span>{MonthAndYear}</span> is ready!</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="180" align="left" style="width: 180px; border: 1px solid #CACACA; padding:          3px; border-radius: 5px">
        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="width: 100%;">
          <tr>
            <td>
              <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="width: 180px;">
                <tr>
                  <td colspan="2" style="width: 100%; padding-bottom: 20px; padding-top:      3px; text-align: center;"><img src=cid:logoLR width="100"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td style="padding-right: 5px;"><img width="65" height="65" style="border-radius: 50%; overflow: hidden;" src=cid:{imgCId}></td>
                  <td>
                    <span style="font-size: 14px; font-weight: 500;">{UserName}</span><br /><span style="font-size: 12px; color:#BDBDBD;">{JobTitle}</span><br /><span style="font-size: 12px; color:#BDBDBD;">{TenantName}</span>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 24px; padding-top: 15px; text-align: center;">
                    <span>{AverageRating}</span>
                  </td>
                  <td style="padding-top: 15px;">
                    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="font-size: 14px;">
                      <tr>
                        <td style="text-align: right; padding-left: 7px;">{RatingsCount}</td>
                        <td style="padding-left: 5px;">Ratings</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td style="text-align: right; padding-left: 7px;">{ReviewsCount}</td>
                        <td style="padding-left: 5px;">Comments</td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td colspan="2" style="padding-top: 15px;">
                    <table cellpadding="0" border="0" style="width: 100%;">
                      <tr>
                        <td style="text-align: center;"><img width="30" height="30" src=cid:{firstStar}></td>
                        <td style="text-align: center;"><img width="30" height="30" src=cid:{secondStar}></td>
                        <td style="text-align: center;"><img width="30" height="30" src=cid:{thirdStar}></td>
                        <td style="text-align: center;"><img width="30" height="30" src=cid:{fourthStar}></td>
                        <td style="text-align: center;"><img width="30" height="30" src=cid:{fifthStar}></td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td width="490" align="left" valign="middle" style=" width: 495px; border: 1px solid #CACACA; vertical-align: middle; padding: 3px; border-radius: 5px">
        <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="left" style="width: 100%;">
          <tr>
            <td>
              <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="3" border="0">
                <tr>
                  {blockTemplate}
                </tr>
              </table>
              <table cellspacing="3" cellpadding="0" style="width: 100%;">
                <tr>
                  <td style="border: 1px solid #CACACA; padding: 3px;">
                    <table cellspacing="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="width: 100%;">
                      <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td style="background-color: #95B3D7; border: 1px solid #B4C9E3; text-align: right; padding: 3px 5px; font-size: 11px;">{MonthAndYear}</td>
                        <td style="background-color: #95B3D7; border: 1px solid #B4C9E3; text-align: right; padding: 3px 5px; font-size: 11px;">Since Go-Live</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td style="border: 1px solid #B4C9E3; background-color: #DBE5F1; padding: 3px 5px; font-size: 11px;">Review Requests Sent</td>
                        <td style="text-align: right; border: 1px solid #B4C9E3; background-color: #DBE5F1; padding: 3px 5px; font-size: 11px;">{SurveysSentPastMonth}</td>
                        <td style="text-align: right; border: 1px solid #B4C9E3; background-color: #DBE5F1; padding: 3px 5px; font-size: 11px;">{SurveysSentAllTime}</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td style="border: 1px solid #B4C9E3; background-color: #FFF; padding: 3px 5px; font-size: 11px;">Review Requests Responded</td>
                        <td style="text-align: right; border: 1px solid #B4C9E3; background-color: #FFF;  padding: 3px 5px; font-size: 11px;">{SurveysRespondedPastMonth}</td>
                        <td style="text-align: right; border: 1px solid #B4C9E3; background-color: #FFF;  padding: 3px 5px; font-size: 11px;">{SurveysRespondedAllTime}</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td style="border: 1px solid #B4C9E3; background-color: #DBE5F1; padding: 3px 5px; font-size: 11px;">Response Rate</td>
                        <td style="text-align: right; border: 1px solid #B4C9E3; background-color: #DBE5F1;  padding: 3px 5px; font-size: 11px;">{ResponseRatePastMonth}</td>
                        <td style="text-align: right; border: 1px solid #B4C9E3; background-color: #DBE5F1;  padding: 3px 5px; font-size: 11px;">{ResponseRateAllTime}</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td style="border: 1px solid #B4C9E3; background-color: #FFF; padding: 3px 5px; font-size: 11px;">Online Review Site Redirects</td>
                        <td style="text-align: right; border: 1px solid #B4C9E3; background-color: #FFF;  padding: 3px 5px; font-size: 11px;">{ReviewRedirectionsPastMonth}</td>
                        <td style="text-align: right; border: 1px solid #B4C9E3; background-color: #FFF;  padding: 3px 5px; font-size: 11px;">{ReviewRedirectionsAllTime}</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td style="border: 1px solid #B4C9E3; background-color: #DBE5F1; padding: 3px 5px; font-size: 11px;">Online Reviews Added</td>
                        <td style="text-align: right; border: 1px solid #B4C9E3; background-color: #DBE5F1;  padding: 3px 5px; font-size: 11px;">{ExternalReviewsAddedPastMonth}</td>
                        <td style="text-align: right; border: 1px solid #B4C9E3; background-color: #DBE5F1;  padding: 3px 5px; font-size: 11px;">{ExternalReviewsAddedAllTime}</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td style="border: 1px solid #B4C9E3; background-color: #FFFF; padding: 3px 5px; font-size: 11px;">Conversion Rate</td>
                        <td style="text-align: right; border: 1px solid #B4C9E3; background-color: #FFF;  padding: 3px 5px; font-size: 11px;">{ConversionRatePastMonth}</td>
                        <td style="text-align: right; border: 1px solid #B4C9E3; background-color: #FFF;  padding: 3px 5px; font-size: 11px;">{ConversionRateAddedAllTime}</td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    {blockComments}
    <!-- end main -->
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" style="padding-bottom: 5px; text-align: left;">Please click on this <a href="{EmailLinkCode}" style="color: #4285F4;">link</a> to view your complete scorecard.</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: why use HTML4 instead of HTML5?

Comment: @tacoshy because it's HTML for email, not the web, and they make their own standards!

Comment: Mate this is pretty good, for an email this complex! But what exactly do you want? The user to scroll left and right, and the email to NOT scale?